# Unusual warning message while extracting data from a Facebook page

Tags: r, facebook

While extracting data from a Facebook page using getPage function in RFacebook, I'm getting an unusual warning message

```
"Warning message:
In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"
```

The oauth authentication process for RFacebook was successful.

A reproducible example:

I'm trying to extract all the posts made in the last 2 months from the Facebook page of Amazon. The code tried so far:

```
page_azn <- getPage(page="Amazon", token, n = 5000, since = '2015/06/01',until = '2015/08/01', feed = T)

100 posts 200 posts 300 posts 400 posts 500 posts 600 posts 700 posts 800 posts 900 posts 1000 posts 1100 posts 1200 posts 1300 posts 1400 posts 1500 posts 1600 posts 1700 posts 1800 posts 1900 posts 2000 posts 2100 posts 2200 posts 2300 posts 2400 posts 2500 posts 2600 posts 2700 posts 2800 posts 2831 posts 

Warning message:
In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

The function is stopping abruptly with the display of warning message.

Any clue on the warning message and how it can be avoided?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, we do not have the `token`. Anyway the error you get most likely is not relate to the package you are using. It says that you are applying a function (`min` it seems to be) to a numeric object of length zero, that's why it returns `Inf`.

Comment: The token I have used here is the temporary authentication token obtained from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/. I had also tried using the oauth authentication token obtained from this blog http://thinktostart.com/analyzing-facebook-with-r/

Comment: The issue is resolved when the Rfacebook package is installed from the github repo of the developer instead of the Cran repo.        library(devtools)
install_github("pablobarbera/Rfacebook/Rfacebook")
library(Rfacebook)